# How to dynamically update content based on route?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-router, axios, api-design

I asked a question not too long ago and got an answer that helped me greatly, but now i'm stumped again. I'm kinda new to React, so still learning a few tips and tricks. I've got a page with a table full of contents fetched from an API based on the year. In the sidebar i've got a list of the possible years. I was stuck originally based on that i only used ComponentDidMount, but got help that I needed an update function when a link was clicked. The problem i'm now having is that I need to press the link twice for the content to update. I can see in the browser that the route has changed, but not the content.

I've tried searching Google, but couldn't find anything. Also tried to use React Router's `this.props.history.push()` since the API bases itself on the `this.props.match.params.yearId` and `this.props.location.search` which equals Year?year=2019(or the clicked year).

```
class YearlyTable extends React.Component {
    state = {
        yearlyTable: [],
        isLoading: false,
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        this.setState({ isLoading: true });
        axios.get(
            `http://localhost/YearlyTable/${this.props.match.params.yearId}${this.props.location.search}`,
            { withCredentials: true }
        ).then(res => {
            const yearlyTable = res.data;
            this.setState({ yearlyTable, isLoading: false });
        }).catch((error) => {
            console.log(error);
        });
    }

    updateData(){
        this.setState({ isLoading: true });
        axios.get(
           `http://localhost/YearlyTable/${this.props.match.params.yearId}${this.props.location.search}`,
           { withCredentials: true }
       ).then(res => {
           const yearlyTable = res.data;
           this.setState({ yearlyTable, isLoading: false });
       }).catch((error) => {
           console.log(error);
       });
    }

    render() {
        if (this.state.isLoading) {
            return (
                <Box style={{textAlign: 'center'}}>
                    <CircularProgress color="primary" />
                </Box>
            );
        }

        // Check what API returns
        console.log(this.state.yearlyTable);

        return (
            // Removed for simplicity
            {this.state.yearlyTable && <ListTable title={this.state.yearlyTable.Title} data={this.state.yearlyTable} />}

            // Removed for simplicity (Sidebar)
            // Example of link(MaterialUI, with RouterLink as React-Router-Dom's Link)
            <Link component={RouterLink} to={'/YearlyTable/Year?year=2018'} onClick={this.updateData.bind(this)}>2018</Link>
        );
    }
}
export default withRouter(YearlyTable);
```

The desired outcome would be for the information to update dynamically without having to press the button twice, since this is a horrible user-experience.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use componentDidUpdate lifecycle method

```
componentDidUpdate(prevProps, prevState) {
    if (prevProps.location.search != this.props.location.search && this.state.isLoading != true) {
        this.setState({ isLoading: true });
        axios.get(
            `http://localhost/YearlyTable/${this.props.match.params.yearId}${this.props.location.search}`,
            { withCredentials: true }
        ).then(res => {
            const yearlyTable = res.data;
            this.setState({ yearlyTable, isLoading: false });
        }).catch((error) => {
            console.log(error);
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: That worked perfectly, just had to change out ```this.props.match.params.yearId``` with ```this.props.location.search``` since this is the parameter that the API worjs out from. Thank you so much, been scratching my head a while now. Haven't heard of the ComponentDidUpdate

Comment: No problem, componentDidUpdate lifecycle method will be called every time either props or state of the particular component changes. You can read about it more here. https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#componentdidupdate